# ArrayList or Map of Distinct Keys, Faster?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, big-o

**Example :-**

List A contains N objects.
List B contains M objects.

One of the objects in list A will match only one of the objects in list B.
The matching criteria is define by me, suppose it is Item No,From Date and Area Code. If these values match then i will copy all the other values from list B's object to list A's object.

**Solution:-** There are two solutions , which one is better or faster?

**Sol 1:-**  Simply execute a for loop to match list B's object in list A.

**Sol 2:-**
**Step 1:-** To create a HashMap < String, Object > from list B.
**Step 2:-** Use that map to fetch the matching record and set values in list A.
If i create a map then the keys will distinct for every object. 
Suppose if list B has 1000 objects then there will be 1000 different keys if i wish to create of HashMap.

Comment: If I understand correctly, for each element of A, you need to find the matching element in B. If B is a list, then each find is O(N), making the whole process O(N^2). If B is a HashMap, each find is O(1), making the whole process O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution is more efficient.

Solution 1 requires a loop over `n` objects (List A) with an inner loop over `m` objects (List B). This is therefore `O(n*m)` or more accurately `O(n^2)`.

Solution 2 requires setup time (build the `Map`) which is `O(m)` followed by one scan of list A (and zero cost of lookup in list B because a `HashMap` lookup is `O(1)`. This is therefore `O(m)+O(n)` which is equivalent to `O(n)`. This is a **much better** solution.

There is an edge case where `m` is **much** bigger than `n` - in this case the setup time and memory costs may be significant.

Comment: We don't know which list is bigger, so O(n*m) is more accurate than O(n^2).

Comment: @Max Not in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0):

First solution has complexity O(N*M).

Second O(N) + O(M), but consumes more memory.

Second algorithm is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Let me recap:

- A (short?) list A
- A long list B
- List A has one item which might match on some criteria to an entry in B
- When that B entry found, copy all other entries in B to A.
- Question: could a Map on B (criteria key to index) help?

You could make a HashSet of the criteria from A and walk through B till first match.

That should be fine too, be fast too.

But yes, a Map/Set should definitely be used. Maybe depending on N << M.